# How to save an R data.frame as CSV with no spaces?

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, save, tidyverse

I have the following `data.frame` that I am saving as `CSV` file. When the `data.frame` is saved as `CSV` I see *one point space* after the `Text` component (see the image). How to avoid the space creation while saving `data.frame` as `CSV`? Thank you

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), to = as.Date("2001-12-31"), by = "days"), Flow = runif(365, 1, 5)) %>% 
      mutate(Year = year(Date), Month = month(Date), Day = day(Date), JDay = yday(Date), Text = rep("FLOW_OUT_",365)) %>% 
      mutate(Format = paste(Text,JDay,"_",Year)) %>% 
      select(8) %>% 
      write.csv(file = "Format.csv")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `paste0` instead of `paste` to avoid creating the spaces as the default `sep` option in `paste` is `sep= " "`

```
...
  mutate(Format = paste0(Text,JDay,"_",Year))
...
```

-full code

```
DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), to = as.Date("2001-12-31"), 
         by = "days"), Flow = runif(365, 1, 5)) %>% 
      mutate(Year = year(Date), Month = month(Date),
      Day = day(Date), JDay = yday(Date), Text = rep("FLOW_OUT_",365)) %>% 
      mutate(Format = paste0(Text,JDay,"_",Year)) %>% 
      select(8)
```

---

Or another option is making use of `sep` argument in `paste`

```
DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), to = as.Date("2001-12-31"), 
             by = "days"), Flow = runif(365, 1, 5)) %>% 
          mutate(Year = year(Date), Month = month(Date),
          Day = day(Date), JDay = yday(Date), Text = rep("FLOW_OUT_",365)) %>% 
          mutate(Format = paste(Text,JDay,"_",Year, sep="")) %>% 
          select(8)
```

-output

```
head(DF)
#           Format
#1 FLOW_OUT_1_2001
#2 FLOW_OUT_2_2001
#3 FLOW_OUT_3_2001
#4 FLOW_OUT_4_2001
#5 FLOW_OUT_5_2001
#6 FLOW_OUT_6_2001
```